# picture element - title attribute

Tags: html

I am using picture element to provide webP images where appropriate like this:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="picture.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="picture.jpg">
  <img src="picture.jpg" alt="alt">
</picture>
```

The questions is where should I place `title` attribute. Should I put it on `img` element or `picture` element?

Answer (score 2):

**I disagree with the previous posters.** I would keep the `title` on the `img` element.

**According to the HTML5 spec's, the `picture` element is a container**, and dependent on the `img` element for rendering of its source element choices. In fact, the `img` element is a requirement for `picture`, not just as a fallback. Therefore, `picture` is just a hollow wrapper around `img` and really doesn't do anything. `img` remains the primary conveyor of images.

The HTML specification goes on to say...

> The picture element is a container which provides multiple sources to
> its contained img element...

...and then

> ...the picture element itself does not display anything; it merely
> provides a context for its contained img element that enables it to
> choose from multiple URLs

That means the `img` element continues to represent the image and so in my opinion must have the `title` element. The fact that the `img` element's `alt` still works and `title`, even when a source image is chosen over `img` by the browser, shows the image element is what is active in the display. Below is an example of how I design images using the `picture` element.

```
<figure aria-labelledby="picturecaption1">
    <picture id="picture1">
        <source srcset="image.webp" type="image/webp" media="(min-width: 800px)" />
        <source srcset="image.gif" type="image/gif" />
        <img id="image1" alt="image:Image Alternate Text" title="The Image Description" src="image.jpg" width="200" height="200" loading="lazy" no-referrer="no-referrer" />
    </picture>
    <figcaption id="picturecaption1">My Image Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should place `title` attribute in `picture` tag because The `<picture>` tag also supports the [Global Attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp) in HTML.

E.g.

```
<picture title="Your goes here">
  <source srcset="picture.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="picture.jpg">
  <img src="picture.jpg" alt="alt">
</picture>
```

Comment: thanks ... any explanation for this? Basically I put all attributes to img tag, but I am not sure with this one so I also need some explanation why to put it to picture element instead of img.

Comment: If you hover over the `picture` element, no matter what the source of the image is, it'll display

Comment: See this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp

Comment: And this https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_picture.asp for quick explanation